# Make new row tag first number and every 4 numbers after?

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to get a new  to fire the first time in my loop and then after 4 counts close the  and then open a new   in my loop i tried doing this with modulus but i don't think I am doing it correctly.

Code I tried:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++): ?>
    <?php if(! (i % 4)): ?>
        <div class="row">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $i; ?>

    <?php if(! (i % 5)): ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

So my results should be:

```
<div class="row">
1 2 3 4
</div>
<div class="row">
5 6 7 8
</div>
<div class="row">
9 10 11 12
</div>
```

etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to :

- start outputting the *before* marker
- then, loop over your items

  - displaying the item
  - and, if `$i % 4 == 3`, putting both an *after* and a *before* markers
- and, finally, display a final *after* marker.

For example, something like this portion of code :

```
$arr = range(1, 15);

echo "before";
for ($i=0 ; $i<count($arr) ; $i++) {
    echo " $i ";
    if ($i % 4 == 3) {
        echo 'after</br />';
        echo 'before';
    }
}
echo "after<br />";
```

Will give that kind of output :

```
before 0 1 2 3 after
before 4 5 6 7 after
before 8 9 10 11 after
before 12 13 14 after
```

Advantage of this solution : you do not have to deal with any specific case *(beginning and end of the loop)* inside the loop.

Comment: what if i wanted to do every 5th one? I have a list of 30

Comment: You'd have to change the `4` and `3` values in the condition, to do a `% 5`, and compare it to `4`, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, you're getting confused with how `%` works, you only ever want to use `% 4` (since you're checking multiples of 4), but compare against different values. `!($i % 4)` will be true for exact multiples of 4, which is not what you want there.

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++): 
    if(i % 4 == 1): ?>
        <div class="row">
    <?php endif;

    echo $i; ?>

    <?php if(i % 4 == 0): ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; 
endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get mismatches the way you're doing it. What you want is probably something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++): ?>
        <?php if(! (i % 4)): ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo $i; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This fires the </div> on the first loop also. how would i change that?

Comment: It should not, since you start at $i = 1?